# Two way binded data appears as string in Polymer

Tags: ecmascript-6, polymer-2.x

I am trying to render polymer template using below code,

```
const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
const htmlTemplate = importDoc.querySelector('template');
shadowRoot.innerHTML = htmlTemplate.innerHTML;
```

But this renders two way binded data also as a string instead of showing the binded value e.g

```
<h1 id ="contactFooter">{{localize('_testVal')}}</h1>
```

is displayed as it is  do anyone have any idea? Two way binding is just example it renders everything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a `<template>` tag you should use `importNode` on the `content`.

e.g.

```
var clone = document.importNode(htmlTemplate.content, true);
shadowRoot.appendChild(clone); 
// note that you will need to clear the shadowRoot if you do rerenderings
// OR you could try
shadowRoot.innerHTML = htmlTemplate.content;
```

see more details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template